# Read a HTML file and show it on a Tkinter window

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I would like to read a HTML and I show it on a Tkinter window. I would like to know if this is possible with any module and if it's how can I do it, as I'm totally lost finding solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "show it on a Tkinter window", do you mean you want the html to appear as it would in a browser, or as it would in a text editor?

Comment: If you are not bind to `TK` take a look to `PyQt` and `webkit`.

Comment: As far as I know there is not Tkinter solution to display a website. You could use phantomjs to create pictures of the website and show those.

Comment: @BryanOakley as a browser

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Unfortunatelly for this, I need to use Tkinter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no support for viewing rendered HTML in a tkinter widget. There was a project (tkhtml) to build a modern web browser using tcl/tk (which is what powers tkinter), but the project never got past a very early alpha release and the last check-in was in 2009.

Comment: Actually TkHtml3 works quite nicely (at least with simpler pages). I created a Python wrapper for it: https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml